# Logstash stopping {:plugin=>"LogStash::Inputs::Http"}

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to run Logstash in an EC2 Ubuntu instance,

but when I run:

```
logstash-5.2.0/bin/logstash -f logstash.conf --debug
```

I get:

```
Starting puma
Trying to start WebServer {:port=>9600}
 start
 Trying to start WebServer {:port=>9601}
[api-service] start
Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9601}
PeriodicPoller: Stopping
 stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
Closing inputs
stopping {:plugin=>"LogStash::Inputs::Http"}
 Closed inputs
```

This is logstash.conf

```
   input 
    {
      http 
      {
        host => "127.0.0.1"
        port => 31311
      }
    }

output

    {
        elasticsearch
        {
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        }

        stdout
        {
            codec => rubydebug
        }
    }
```

When I run

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty'
```

I get:

```
{
  "name" : "QrRfI_U",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "LLdvAaAsQSCULTfl_b4xIA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.2.0",
    "build_hash" : "24e05b9",
    "build_date" : "2017-01-24T19:52:35.800Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.4.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

So elasticsearch is running fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you have your `hosts` as:

```
hosts => "localhost"
```

And make sure that the `http` *port* which you've mentioned above is not bound to any other process.

If that's not the case just to make sure, run `plugin list` and check whether **http-input** plugin does exist.